# Imaginary part reduction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have following expression 
$\sqrt[3]{a + bi} + \sqrt[3]{a - bi} =$

How can I calculate it? I would like to have a solution with imaginary part reduction because Im sure that solution is a real number.

Comment: Hints: 1) Write $a+bi = r e^{i\theta}$, 2) use DeMoivre's formula.

Comment: Thank you. DeMoivre's formula works perfectly for this :)

Comment: @rogerl it looks like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 1) Write $a+bi = r e^{i\theta}$, 2) use DeMoivre's formula. Note that if $a+bi = r e^{i\theta}$, then $a-bi = r e^{-i\theta}$, so
$$(r e^{i\theta})^{1/3} + (r e^{-i\theta})^{1/3}
    = r^{1/3}\left(
       \cos\frac{\theta}{3} + i\sin\frac{\theta}{3}
        + \cos\left(-\frac{\theta}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(-\frac{\theta}{3}\right)
      \right)
    = 2r^{1/3}\cos\frac{\theta}{3}.
$$